# Creating a Google App Script programmatically with the API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-api

Is it possible to create a brand new google app script programmatically and attach him to a specific google doc?

Or in any other way, to make 1 bound script and make several google docs to share him as the same bound script?

Comment: A good Stack Overflow question includes an explanation of what you have already tried.  It *is* possible to programmatically create a new Apps Script file with content.  Even though the original script is bound, I believe that it can still be used as a library in other Apps Script files.  And an add-on can do that also, but it's better to have a stand alone Apps Script file as the basis for an add-on or library.  I believe that the new Apps Script API can deploy scripts and new versions.  But you are asking a very broad question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Possible through the API.

- [google-apps-script-api](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script-api)[Apps script api](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/manage-projects)

> Use project.create. You can provide a project title. You can also create a bound script by providing the Google Drive ID of a Google Doc, Sheet, Form, or Slides file to act as the script's parent.

- [clasp](/questions/tagged/clasp) [commandline interface](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp)

> clasp is an open-source tool, separate from the Apps Script platform, that lets you develop and manage Apps Script projects from your terminal rather than the Apps Script editor.